# How to debug regex strings sent to PHP function?

Tags: php, regex, debugging

I use this function to replace thousands of regex codes:

```
function preg_replace_assoc(array $replace, $subject) {
   return preg_replace(array_keys($replace), array_values($replace), $subject);
}
```

Now I upgraded to PHP 5.3.10 and I get some errors like:

`Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: missing ) at offset 18`

`Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 35`

`Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier '-'`

How can I debug this? PHP doesn't print the array keys.

Comment: Before `preg_replace` add `var_dump($replace);` line and see what it shows.

Comment: Seems like it returns arrays, each uíncluding all instances of the function call. But how to find the wrong regex string?

Comment: ok can you place a part of it here so that we can also investigate it and suggest you a fix.

Comment: it's thousands of lines like https://dpaste.de/FG7W

Comment: Looks like you have bad regex where you have `(*ANYCRLF)`

Comment: `(*ANYCRLF)` is proper PHP regex: https://twitter.com/BigglesZX/status/24577555669

Comment: Oh ok, but you're also using `/m` which won't match newline anyway so why bother about `(*ANYCRLF)`

Comment: Anyone else? I tried `die( var_dump($replace) )` but that just stops at the first function call.

Answer (score 0):

Write a simple loop for the array, and do key-value replaces one by one - before replace, print the key-value pair.

This way you will know which is the offending expression.

Comment: Thanks, I removed all and added them blockwise, nailing it down per block then.